# Extract first letter of the last word in "full name" field. - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So first time posting here and my problem is I need to change middle name to middle initial if there is middle name in full name field using python pandas.

```
for example) 
Keys, Alicia ------> Keys, Alicia 
Keys, Alicia T ----->Keys, Alicia T 
Keys, Alicia Mary -----> Keys, Alicia M 
Pitt, John Paul -----> Pitt, John P 
Pitt, John Paul John --> Pitt, Jon Paul J
```

---

So if there is no middle name then keep the full name values,
if there is a middle initial then keep the middle initial
if there is a middle name then change middle name to middle initial.

I've been playing with string split but I do not have a good way to know how to tackle all the cases.

Any help are appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: what does your dataframe look like

Comment: I'll ask you this: how can you be sure those names are given like you think they are. What about foreigner's names? Or is this just a programming example?

Answer (score 0):

Judging strictly by the provided example, you could use the following piece of code, which replaces the last word with its first letter, to transform every string:

```
def transform(name):
    words = name.split()
    if len(words) < 3:
        return name
    words[-1] = words[-1][0]
    return " ".join(words)
```

Of course, if the middle name is not the last word of the string, you'd have to find the middle name *somehow* and use its index instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
# Get the first letter of the last name
def letterofname(name):
   # Separate each word into a list
   words = name.split(' ')
   # Get the last char
   last_name = words[len(words) - 1]
   last_char = last_name[len(list(last_name)) - 1]

   return last_char
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a regular expression to substitute those last names with their initials. No complex logic there, just a one-liner :) I made an example regex and substitution for you:

See: https://regex101.com/r/s3Z83O/1